# SMTP Authentication Error in Python django project

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail, blogs

## Getting SMTP Error in my project.

When attempting to send the verification code after providing the user's email and password and clicking the corresponding button, an error is encountered. The error message is as follows: "SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/ (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError n13-20020a170902968d00b001b04b1bd774sm11264751plp.208 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')".

These are the codes that i used in my Settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USER='user_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PASS='userpassword'

print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')) #i'm getting NONE after printing.

EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

If you know the problem then Please help.

Comment: Did you read the document in the link?

Comment: yes i did but still confused..i tried to change the passwords that gmail gave me(16 digit password) but still im confused.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the users actually Gmail password.

you need to enable 2fa and create an apps password or use xoauth2 and request authorization of the user

Answer (score -1):

This error generally means that either email or password is incorrect. For that, you can reset the password and reset your env vars with updated information.